# Can I automount /etc on a different partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, fstab

This seems like a chicken-and-egg problem.

Inside the `/etc/fstab` file on the root partition, can I specify a different partition to mount at the `/etc` mount-point, such as:

```
/dev/sda6 /etc defaults 0 0
```

Could this cause any problems?
Assume that I have some sensible contents on the new `/etc` , including the identical fstab and proper init and rc directories.

As a slight rephrasing of the question: What is the order of operations of booting?
Is `/etc/fstab` checked first for mounting drives before the rest of init.d scripts are run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a terrible idea. You should not and can not put `/etc` on a different partition from `/`. The kernel searches for `/etc/fstab` and a bunch of other configuration files as it boots from `/`. If `/etc` was on a different, as-yet unknown partition, how would the kernel find `/etc/fstab` to mount it?

Comment: The kernel does not use `/etc/fstab` for anything. It's the initramfs that mounts `/` (and often `/usr`), and init running from `/` mounts the rest.

Comment: @grawity - that's true, I was trying to be quick in my reply. I was just using the word "kernel" to refer to "the general startup process." Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are talking about Debian.

[This](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch03.en.html) tells you everything if you have it using the traditional init system.  Specifically:

> The "/sbin/init" program is executed as the first program and performs
>   the main boot process. The Debian normally uses the traditional
>   sysvinit scheme with the sysv-rc package. See init(8), inittab(5), and
>   "/usr/share/doc/sysv-rc/README.runlevels.gz" for the exact
>   explanation. This main boot process essentially goes through the
>   following.
>
> - The Debian system goes into runlevel N (none) to initialize the system by following the "/etc/inittab" description.
> - The Debian system goes into runlevel S to initialize the system under the single-user mode to complete hardware initialization etc.
> - The Debian system goes into one of the specified multi-user runlevels (2 to 5) to start the system services.

What happens per runlevel is that everything in `/etc/rcX.d` is executed, in alphabetical order, where `X` is the run level.

So, if you `cd /etc/rcS.d`, you will see a bunch of symlinks to `/etc/init.d`, that begin with a number.  The number is there to determine the order.  The ones beginning with `S` are executed when the run level is entered, and the ones beginning with `K` are executed when the run level is exited.  Runlevel "S" is just used for initialization so there are no `K` links there.

Tread with caution here if you modify or rename anything.  Make sure you test your scripts before subjecting yourself to a boot process.

Ok, going to try to actually answer the question now, with the above information as necessary background.

Under Debian the `/etc/rc.S/S11mountall.sh` is where the crucial "mount everything in fstab" happens.  However, `fstab` is consulted to mount the root filesystem at `/etc/rc.S/S07checkroot.sh`.

If you use `fstab` to automount a new `/etc`, everthing in `/etc/rc.S/S12*` and higher will then be using the `/etc` on your "overlay" volume.  However, you need a valid `/etc/fstab` on the root volume at that time beforehand.

Other things that `/etc` is consulted for include `/etc/hostname`, possibly some stuff related to `udev` (which is extremely important).  You need to look at all the scripts from `/etc/rc.S/S11*` and lower to know exactly.  If you really want no `/etc` at all until it is mounted from an external partition you are looking at modifying these scripts.  It's probably not going to be as simple as switching the order of `/etc/rc.S/S12mountall.sh` to, for example `/etc/rc.S/S00mountall.sh`, but you possibly could add a new script that brings in `/etc` from an external partition earlier.

You can use the Linux `mount --bind` command to mount the root volume's original `/etc` somewhere (like `/etc_from_rootfs`) to copy it over when you make changes to `fstab` or other files that are consulted before `/etc/rc.S/S12mountall.sh`.

The Linux kernel does not do what Windows does, which is to use and require the presence of the registry before and during boot.  The kernel itself will boot fine (but not terribly useably in 99% of instances) with no `/etc`, but it's up to userspace programs called after (starting with `init`), which then look at `/etc`, to get a decent user environment ready.

Sound complicated?  It is, which is why listening to @MattDMo is likely prudent.

Comment: This is informative, but doesn't really address my question.

Comment: Haha, now that I re-read it, it didn't, but hopefully it explained how the order of boot operations are determined under Debian and where to go to change what it does, which is very customizable.